# ¿Como leer una JSON que es enviado desde un webservice en Android?

Tags: php, sql, android-studio, json

Hola tengo un archivo php en un hosting, este archivo consulta y devuelve los datos por medio de un JSONArray.

```
$idusu=$_GET['pkusu'];
$pass=$_GET['passw'];
if($_GET['opc']=="1")
{
   $sql="consulta...";
    $r2=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($r2));
    {
      while ($arr=mysql_fetch_array($r2))
      {
        echo json_encode($arr);
      }  
    } 
}
```

En android creo un JASONArray y les paso los datos por getstring
esto para pasar los datos a otro activity y checo el tipo de usuario

```
JSONArray ja = null;
try
{
 ja = new JSONArray(result);
 pk=ja.getString(0);
 nomb=ja.getString(1);
 tipo=ja.getString(2);
 if (tipo == "x")
 {
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
   i.putExtra("nomb", nomb);
   startActivity(i);
   finish();
 }
 else
 if(tipo=="y")
 {
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProductosAdmin.class);
   i.putExtra("nomb", nomb);
   startActivity(i); 
   finish();           
 }
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No entiendo que esta mal en el código si al ejecutar el php directo en el url de la página si muestra el JSON pero no lo muestra en android.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar retrofit o volley para parsear los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Para leer tu `JSON` en android una alternativa es por medio de un `Asynctask`, existen otras librerias como ***retrofit***, ***volley***.

En este caso de mostrare la forma de realizarlo con un Asynctask ([ver documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html))
  y luego mostrar tus datos en un `listview` para verificar que los lee, luego puedes realizar la acción que deseas. quitando el `listview`, etc

```
// declaramos dos variables para manejar el tiempo de conexión y un String para almacenar-mostrar los datos depues en el listview
String pregrespcomment; 
ListView mostrarr;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;

 private class leer_datos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(ganancias_totales.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tConsultando...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                url = new URL("http://www.tu_sitio/tu_archivo.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try 
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();  
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {  
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    return (result.toString());

                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pdLoading.dismiss();
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(ganancias_totales.this);
                alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar los datos. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
                alertaDeError.create();
                alertaDeError.show();
            } else {
                //Existen Datos
                List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
                        try {
                            preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        try {
                            assert preguntaDatos != null;
                            pregrespcomment =" datos: " + "\n" +">+ preguntaDatos.getString("pkusu"),preguntaDatos.getString("pass");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        preguntas.add(pregrespcomment);

                    }

                    //crear el Adapter.
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ejemplo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
                    mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(ganancias_totales.this);
                    alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
                    alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no existen datos. Intentelo de nuevo.");
                    alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    });
                    alertaDeError.create();
                    alertaDeError.show();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me sirvio bastante

Comment: Te ha funcionado @Leonardo ?

Comment: Perdon por la tardanza, y si me es de mucha ayuda gracias @Ashley G.

Comment: Me alegro, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada para cerrar @Leonardo